# undefined color `none' when using callouts package

Tags: color, callout

In my attempt of putting some text over an image using the callouts package, I copied the the example code form [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) (you have to scroll down a bit to the answer of user knut) where the package is loaded with the colour options set to `[wby]` and it works fine.
But if I try and remove the colour options, according to the documentation that came with the package it should display the text and arrow in black and no background, but instead I get the error

`` ! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `none'.  See the xcolor package documentation for explanation. ``

Nobody else seems to be having this issue so either I misunderstood something in the documentation or something is wrong with my code.
The following reproduces my problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{callouts}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\def\scale{0.7}
\begin{annotate}{
\includegraphics[width=\scale\textwidth]{Carc.png}}{\scale}
    \helpgrid
    \note{0,0}{Center}
    \callout{4,3}{Mushrom}{3,2}
    \arrow{-3,-2.4}{-4.5,-3}
    %And raw tikz
    \draw[very thick,red] (-4,4) rectangle (-3,3);
\end{annotate}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Anyone has suggestions what it might be?

Comment: My bad, added the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Set the `\bgcol` command to a quitable color. The manual mentions calling the package with `[ background = gray , arrow = red ]` which works. If you do not explicitly set the `background` color, it will use the default value which is the non existing color `none`.

Comment: But since it's the default value of the package I assumed it would work! I'm guessing that a bad assumption, I can work with a background but I would rather have none so I cover as little as possible of the image. Is there a work around, maybe to set it to some level of transparency? I looked into that also but I would have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @Skipjack3 Indeed, it's just a bad choice of the default value for optional argument to `\helpgrid`. Just do `\helpgrid[black]`.